# My old picture app quits working on Android 11 S20. BitmapFactory has outWidth at -1

Tags: android, image, bitmapfactory

My app takes a picture then compresses if necessary. It gets an error on new s20 phones.

```
BitmapFactory.Options scaleOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
scaleOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, scaleOptions);
Log.d("ImageCompressor", "Scale out width " + scaleOptions.outWidth);
Log.d("ImageCompressor", "Scale out height " + scaleOptions.outHeight);
```

On all older phones and tablets the outWidth and Height logs would have a pos value

with the new s20 they are '-1'

What does it mean when the values are -1?
the target apk is still 23

I have always used the following method to take the pic

```
String extStorageDirectory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();

File mFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/location_pics");
```

after making up a filename

```
picFileNamePath = mFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/full" + filename;
picDir = mFolder;
uriToSend = Uri.fromFile(file);
uriToCompress = Uri.fromFile(fileFull);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fileFull));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

the file name that exists after but I cannot decode is named
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.hgs.tview/files/Pictures/location_pics/fullDORAND_1_1.jpg

Comment: as you can see here https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java;l=367;bpv=0;bpt=1
outWidth will be set to -1 if there is an error trying to decode. So it looks like there is an decode error

Comment: I would probalby start to check where the 'path' does to in this device

Comment: Indeed. Where did you obtain that path? And what exactly is its value? And why dont you use an uri?

Comment: Thanks - decode error. The file may be blocked. I will edit to show how I get path that has worked for older phones

Comment: Do not use Uri.fromFile but use a FileProvider.

Comment: Using FileProvider worked, after upgrading Android Studio and Refactoring to androidx,  Thank you.